# Managing multiple python interpreters

Tags: python, pip, path, pythoninterpreter

I had this problem for several months now.
I have multiple versions of python interpreters located in different folders inside my mac. I have pycharm and anaconda installed. This is so far not an issue as I know that this would enable the choice to configure the environment per project. The problem starts when I try to install a library then it accepts the downloads but library fail to run when imported in the code field. also, the version of the python are the same.

I think it is matter of `$Path` pointing to the right interpreter.

side problems:

- `brew` does not work, `pip` does.
- I don't know which packages of libraries installed in which interpreter.
- I am confused with the use of `conda` vs `pip` vs `brew`. do I need all of them for package management or one is sufficient.
- I would like to know the easiest way to check the `$PATH` and modifies to point to the right interpreter in the easiest way possible.

Thank you for your help .

[image]

Comment: Look into pyenv, its main purpose is managing different python versions. You can use `which` to figure out which executable you're using. For example `which python3` or `which pip3`. Easiest way to check the $PATH is `echo`ing it

Answer (score 0):

how do you install the libraries?
a possible reason could be ambiguity of pip versions and python interpreters.
first, upgrade the corresponding pip modules of every python interpreter.

```
python3.x -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

after doing so, install modules with

```
python3.x -m pip install $MODULE
```

instead of `pip3 install $MODULE`.  this way you will use the corresponding module and not executable that might be relevant for single version.